# Ajax alerta sucesso porém não insere os dados

Tags: php, ajax, sql-insert, actions

Eu já fiz um insert sem usar o ajax e funcionou normal, quando usei o ajax e retornou sucesso pensei que tava tudo certo porem quando fui olhar no banco os dados não estavam lá

#### Código JS Funcionando

```
function adicionaUsuario(){
var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
var nome = $('#nome').val();
var usuario = $('#usuario').val();
var senha = $('#senha').val();

$.ajax({

method: 'POST',
url: "action/addUsuario.php",
data: {'tipo': tipo, 'nome': nome, 'usuario': usuario, 'senha': senha},
cache: false,
success: function(msg){

    alert('Usuario inserido com sucesso');

 }

});


}
```

#### action/addUsuario.php

```
<?php
require_once("../conexao.php");
require_once("../class/Usuario.php");
require_once("../class/UsuarioDao.php");

$nomeAdd = $_POST['nome'];
$usuarioAdd = $_POST['usuario'];
$senhaAdd = $_POST['senha'];
$tipoAdd = $_POST['tipo'];

$usuario = new Usuario($nomeAdd, $usuarioAdd, $senhaAdd, $tipoAdd);

$usuarioDao = New UsuarioDao($conexao);

$usuarioDao->adicionaUsuario($usuario);
```

#### DAO

```
function adicionaUsuario(Usuario $usuario) {
    $usuario->setNome(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $usuario->getNome()));
    $usuario->setUsuario(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $usuario->getUsuario()));


    $query = "Insert Into usuario (nome,usuario,senha,tipo) values ('{$usuario->getNome()}','{$usuario->getUsuario()}','{$usuario->getSenha()}',{$usuario->getTipo()})";

    return mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);

}
```

#### Form

```
< form method="POST">

    <div class="center" style="margin-top:10px;">

        <h1 align="center"> Adicionar Usuário </h1> 

        <table class="table">

            <tr>
                <td><h3>Tipo: </h3></td>
                <td> <select id="tipo" name="tipo" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 17px;">
                        <option value="2">Usuario</option>
                        <option value="1">Administrador</option>  
                    </select> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><h3>Nome: </h3></td>
                <td><input id ="nome"class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" style="margin-top: 17px;"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><h3>Usuario: </h3></td>
                <td><input id ="usuario"class="form-control" type="text" name="usuario" style="margin-top: 17px;"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><h3>Senha: </h3></td>
                <td><input id="senha" class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" style="margin-top: 17px;" required></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <button type="submit" onclick="adicionaUsuario()" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Adicionar</button>
    </div>
< /form>
```

Comment: Na função adicionar, se fizer um echo de `$usuario->getNome()` por ex, ele imprime o nome?

Comment: Queria saber como testar isso, pois não sei como consigo ver getNome() usando ajax pq a pagina não vai mudar para a paginada action (estou começando a aprender como usar jquery, ajax)

Comment: se eu tento dá um console.log(data). dentro do success diz que ela nao está definida

Comment: faça `console.log(msg);`

Comment: Ele diz "Undefined index nome na action/addUsuario.php" 
"Undefined index usuario na action/addUsuario.php" 
"Undefined index senha na action/addUsuario.php"

aqui para melhor visualização> [http://prnt.sc/cwmjwh]

Comment: A string que apareceu apos o tipo, ela aparece na URI mas pq? se eu to usando o metodo POST

Comment: como vc tá chamando a função `adicionarUsuario()`? é um form?

Comment: Através do botão dentro do form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifique a forma como os dados são setados no **data** do ajax:

data: {'tipo': tipo, 'nome': nome, 'usuario': usuario, 'senha': senha},

Deve funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou! tem alguma forma de os dados que eu inserir nao aparecer na URI? sempre que adiciono fica assim: http://localhost/Base/adicionarUsuario.php?tipo=2&nome=nomeDois&usuario=usuarioDois&senha=senhaDois

Comment: e os dados que foram inseridos

Comment: e agora, está inserindo os dados porém não tá mostrando o alert, queria mostrar ele, alguma dica?

Comment: Posta o teu código com as modificações que vc fez

Comment: Pronto editei com o código funcionando

Comment: Cara, coloquei para executar o ajax na minha máquina local e exibiu o alert de boa. A única coisa que fiz corrigir o espaço antes de < form method="POST"> e < /form>.

Comment: Eu notei que aqui por algum motivo nao me pergunte qual, quando da erro ele vai pro success, agora que está funcionando e eu botei error: function() { alert("teste") }, sempre que insere ele vai e dá o alert teste, mas tudo bem eu queria mesmo aprender a inserir com ajax e já estouc onseguindo!